# jQuery horizontal Slider not working on one page the other page is working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to see why this slider on this page doesn't work: http://bit.ly/tmKdEQ

Which uses the id #winecycle.

And the slider on this page: http://bit.ly/w0rsDv works fine which uses the exact same code.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true,
            continuous: true,
            speed:      1900,
            auto:           true,
            pause:          3000,
            controlsShow:   false

        });

        $("#sliderFood").easySlider({ 
            auto: true,
            continuous: true,
            speed:      1900,
            auto:           true,
            pause:          3000,
            controlsShow:   false
        });

        $("#winecycle").easySlider({ 
            auto: true,
            continuous: true,
            speed:      1900,
            auto:           true,
            pause:          3000,
            controlsShow:   false
        });

        $("#sliderHomeWidget").easySlider({ 
            auto: true,
            continuous: true,
            speed:      1600,
            auto:           true,
            pause:          3000,
            controlsShow:   false
        });


    }); 
</script>


<div id="winecycle">
<ul>        
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php query_posts('category_name=wine-cycle&showposts=9&order=ASC'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>  
    <div>No Images can be found</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just apply the slider once: `$("#slider, #sliderFood, #winecycle, [etc]").easySlider({});`. They all have the same values anyways (except for the speed on sliderHomeWidget, but who's gonna notice 200 milliseconds?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the food page the images marked with `<li>` and on the wine with `<p>`.  Try changing the wine images to be marked up with `<li>` and see how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up when you have been working on something for a while you become blind to certain aspects of it. Having a different perspective always helps. Your right is was the <p> tags, as they are automatically generated it stopped the EasySlider from picking up the list item as there was no list item. As they weren't surrended by <li></li>.